# Spark refuse connection to master

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to setup a small Spark cluster for testing. The cluster consists of 3 workers and one master.
On each node I setup Java, scala and spark.
The configuration files are as follow:
**spark-defaults.conf:**

```
spark.master                 spark://test01.scem:7077
 spark.eventLog.enabled      true
 spark.eventLog.dir         hdfs://test01.scem/user/spark/applicationHistory
 spark.executor.memory       4g
 spark.serializer            org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
 spark.driver.memory         5g
 spark.yarn.archive          hdfs://test01.scem/user/spark
```

**spark-env.sh**

```
export SPARK_CONF_DIR=/usr/hadoop/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/conf
export SPARK_LOG_DIR=/var/log/spark
export SPARK_PID_DIR=/var/run/spark
export HADOOP_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME:-/usr/hadoop}
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_CONF_DIR:-/usr/hadoop/etc/hadoop}
```

I am able to start all nodes by (start-all.sh), but I recieve an error message on starting the shell (spark-shell).
 I tried all available methods to view the UI for Spark cluster, but no luck, any help please.
The error message I receive is:

```
WARN client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master test01.scem:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
```

The jps of each node is :

> Master {18097 JobHistoryServer, 21249 Jps, 20758 NameNode, 20440
>   ResourceManager}
>
> slaves {11456 JobHistoryServer, 15409 Jps, 15092 DataNode, 14799
>   NodeManager}

Comment: can you post the output of `jps` in terminal after you start all nodes and before you apply spark-shell?

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, it's posted now

Comment: it seems that you started hadoop cluster only and not spark cluster. so can you also update with the steps you are starting the cluster

Comment: Thanks Ramesh you are right. I was unable to start the workers and master. I started them later by using "bash"  (bash start-master.sh) and (bash start-slave.sh spark://test01:7077). Now I can see the three workers!

Comment: great to hear that :) is your problem solved? if yes then answer the question below with what you did. :)

Answer (score 0):

check if you can ping the master. if that's true check if the port 7077 is occupied on master using netstat command. if both are true it may be a firewall issue